# I have done a simple update adding two sounds and now some users are reporting that when thy go on the app it quits straight away

Tags: ios, app-store, ios6, updates, parse-framework

I have a soundboard app, which has always worked fine, but since the update i am getting reports the app is just quitting when opened, when i test this on 5 devices it work fine on all of them. This is my first update of ios6 so it could be something to do with that, also in this update I had to update the parse framework, this could of messed something up.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as i need to fix whatever is wrong with it and fast. Thanks

Comment: You'll need to try and get the crash reports, or everyone's in the dark.

Comment: @jrturton in itunes connect there is no crash reports :/ any other way i can get them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very old but i may aswell answer it even though no one cares. It was due to me adding frameworks that were required for the parse framework but weren't supported by ios5 and they were set to required, i changed them to optional and it was working fine.